# How to convert a list to a tree with multiple object instances and cycle detection

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

**Problem**

I need to convert a flat list to a tree. In opposite to the solutions I've found I also need to consider that the same object can be multiple times associated to a parent. And I need to detect cycles, so that this won't run in an endless loop. Does anyone have a good algorithm for that?

Example list (please note that the list items could be in random order with random ids):

```
null -> 1
1 -> 2
1 -> 3
2 -> 3
3 -> 4
```

So the tree would look like this:

```
null
  --> 1
    --> 2
       --> 3
         --> 4
    --> 3
       --> 4
```

In other words, the structure of node 4 (if it had children) would have to be duplicated.

**Code**

I have an approach in Java, but that one works only without the `3 -> 4` association.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

public class List2Tree {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // load list
        List<Relation> relations = load();

        // convert to tree
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = convertUsingObject( relations);

        // logging
        log( root);

        // create ui
        JTree tree = new JTree(root);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }


    /**
     * Load a relation list
     * @return
     */
    public static List<Relation> load() {

        List<Relation> relations = new ArrayList<>();
        relations.add(new Relation(null, 1));
        relations.add(new Relation(1, 2));
        relations.add(new Relation(1, 3));
        relations.add(new Relation(2, 3));
        relations.add(new Relation(3, 4));

        return relations;
    }


    /**
     * Convert the list to a tree using the relation object
     * @param relations
     * @return
     */
    public static DefaultMutableTreeNode convertUsingObject( List<Relation> relations) {

        // create a map of all possible tree node objects
        Map<Relation,DefaultMutableTreeNode> nodeMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer,DefaultMutableTreeNode> childNodeMap = new HashMap<>();
        for( Relation relation: relations) {

            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode( relation);
            nodeMap.put( relation, node);
            childNodeMap.put( relation.child, node);

        }

        // create root
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode( new Relation( null, null));

        // iterate through all children, find the tree node and link the child to the parent
        for( Relation relation: relations) {

            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = nodeMap.get( relation);

            if( relation.parent == null) {

                root.add(node);

            } else {

                DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = childNodeMap.get( relation.parent);

                parent.add( node);

            }

        }

        return root;
    }

    /**
     * Logging
     * @param root
     */
    public static void log( DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {

        // log
        Enumeration e = root.preorderEnumeration();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(e.nextElement());
        }


    }

    /**
     * Parent-child relationship
     */
    public static class Relation {

        Integer parent;
        Integer child;

        public Relation(Integer parent, Integer child) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.child = child;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "" + child;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here.  If the lines `1 -> 3;
2 -> 3` indicate that two different `Node 3` instances are created then you don't have a problem, only the "name" you used to identify the nodes is not unique.  This interpretation is supported by the fact that the two instances could have different sets of children. You haven't told us if there are more attributes that need to be shared between multiple instances named `3`.  This smells a lot like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Please clarify the problem you are ***actually*** trying to solve.

Comment: I updated the question. Please note that the list is in random order, the ids are random. Yes, 2 different `Node 3` instances have to be created. But only 1 `Node 1` instance.

Comment: Still not clear.  Do you also have two distinct instances of a node labeled `4`? Does the line `3 -> 4` really mean "Find all nodes labeled 3 and add a child node labeled 4"?

Comment: Yes, the list shows only 1 entry of `Node 4`, there it is attached to `Node 3`, so in the tree it has to be duplicated, since there are 2 entries of `Node 3` in the list. The real problem starts when `Node 4` has children, because one would have to duplicate sub-trees.

Comment: I still think you need to explain the higher-level problem.  You are guiding us down a preferred solution path based on a possibly flawed understanding of the rquirements.

Comment: How can you have cycles if you allow objects to be duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

First, you get to need your input in a reasonable order. Then, you can do what Jim suggested in the comments: when you encounter a new relation `x -> y`, find all nodes `x` (using a map) and create a new child `y` for each of them.

The order can be defined as follows: Every relation `x -> y` must be before any other relation `y -> z`. This is basically a precedence relation of the nodes. If relation `x -> y` is contained in the relation list, that means that node `x` has to be processed before node `y`. So start by building this precedence graph (no duplicate nodes here). Then serialize it. If it's not possible to serialize the graph, there is a cycle. Then, process the nodes in the serialized order (i.e. create new children for every outgoing arc).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, the solution is a bit comples but still straightforward.

Here's some pseudocode: Given any `a -> b`:

```
aList = list of references to all existing nodes labeled a
bList = list of references to all existing nodes labeled b
if (bList is empty)
    bList.add(new b)
for (a : aList)
    for (b : bList)
        if the subtree rooted at b contains a 
            throw CycleDetectedException
        c = Deep Clone(b)
        a.addChild(c);
```

I believe, but have not proven, that since the `b` subtree gets cloned, cycles can be created only if `b`'s subtree contains an instance of `a`